# Select Query is not working with WHERE clause when there is a space in column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Select Query is not working with WHERE clause when there is a space in column value. since my table column value has space in it. When I copied same value from query result and put that with where clause, it doesn't return any result.
.

```
select * from myTable
```

[image]

if I run below query

```
select * From myTable where OldLoanNumber ='000000010383904 '
```

, it doesn't return any result
[image]

SQL Server Version is 18.6 as shown in pic
[image]

Am I missing anything or any settings related to SQL Query Analyzer?

Comment: Why is it that a trailing space belongs on the end of the column value?  Did you try it without the space?

Comment: Read about [surprising behavior trailing spaces](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/04/surprising-behavior-trailing-spaces/), or (if you do not like to visit an 'uknown' site, try this one: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces

Comment: are you sure that is a space and not a tab?  Trailing spaces should be ignored.

Comment: @SteveC, in db data is stored like , this I can't change that now.

Comment: @jmoreno, Ohhh My god, you are right , that's not space that is actually a tab, i got the result by chnaging the space to tab. Tons of Thanks ! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANSI standard says that string comparisons are to be padded to the same length, and I have observed that behavior many times.

I believe the most likely cause of your problem is the last character being a tab or other non space character that simply **looks** like a space to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ltrim, RTrim or Trim like for example

select * From myTable where Trim(OldLoanNumber) =Trim('000000010383904 ')

Comment: I tried that already select * From myTablewhere RTrim(OldLoanNumber) = RTrim('000000010383904 ') and select * From myTablewhere Trim(OldLoanNumber) = Trim('000000010383904 '), It's not working gives me no result

Comment: maybe that space character is not really a space but some other character, please check